What happened to the job market for assembly programmers once high level languages became mainstream?
At some point it became easier and faster to write high level code than assembly. I'm curious about the transition - right now a full time assembly programmer is rare indeed, although there are still some niches for it. Was there an industry upheaval where jobs became obsolete over night? Did a lot of people lose their jobs?

Most programmers are happy to learn a new language. It isn't like overnight assembly was "obsolete" and there were a whole bunch of high-level language programmers untainted by assembly magically available. Programmers are programmers.

This is based on a misconception.  Languages of all levels have always been used.  There is no such thing as "mainstream"

Some of the assembly programmers became compiler writers.

The run time system for a language was often written in assembly.  Developing, maintianing or supporting the runtime system generally called for assembly laguage skills.

High-level languages have been around since 1950s (e.g. COBOL 1959), while games were routinely written in assembler well into the 1980s and beyond. The overlap era is huge. In practice, what happened was the market for programmers expanded almost continuously.

Its worth calling out that a lot of games were written in assembly until around 1993-1996, when 3d consoles came out (3DO Interactive Multiplayer, Sega Saturn, PS1, N64). 3d was complex enough that most game studios switched to higher level languages, mostly C.

@MooingDuck It isn't just that the complexity (of 3D or whatever) required high level languages. The first 4 generations (as defined here ) of video game consoles pretty much required the super-high level of optimization of code size and speed that you can realistically only get with assembly.

Programming is programming.  In the last decade I haven't touched any language I learned in school.  So what?  The fundamental skill is "programming", not "8086 assembly" or "basic".  It's all effectively dialects to an underlying concept.

The use of legacy code meant that there was still demand for assembly coding decades after visual and OO coding became the norm. The Y2K bug demonstrated this.

It's worth pointing out that C is a Mid level language,  not a higher level language.  C# certainly is but not the original.

@Elliot C is a high level programming language. Don't let anybody tell you otherwise.

@JeremyP This fact comes from The C Programming language by Kernighan & Ritchie. Tell me about a better source. More recently .NET has added a great deal to it but the Original language, as explained in this book, was a Mid-level language.

It's not a fact. There's no such thing as a mid level language. A language either maps onto a particular machine architecture or it maps on to a higher level abstraction. C is in the latter category. Here is a man talking about C as a high level language.

Interesting but does not contradict the statement in the current edition of The C Programming Language which describes it as a Mid-Level language. In the video he is describing C in the context of bootstrapping languages into higher level ones. More importantly the syntax of C is filled with old use of pointers to data and their use to manipulate data. This is not used in C#. End of Transmission

This isn't like "what happened to the stable hands when cars replaced horses". It is more like "what happened to the mechanics who worked on manual transmissions when automatic transmissions became more popular" - they learned how to fix automatic transmissions, but they still work on manual transmissions when needed.
Assembly language was constantly changing anyway. Arguably, until the IBM System/360 in 1964, pretty much every significant new system had a new assembly language to learn. By that same time period, FORTRAN and COBOL were well established and many other high-level languages were available or under development.

At some point it became easier and faster to write high level code than assembly.

Arguably that was at the point that the first high-level languages were developed. But "easier and faster to write" was not, and still is not, the only criteria in a programming language. If it was then assembly would have totally disappeared decades ago. There are still situations where assembly has advantages:

Smaller code - Less of an issue today but a big deal when 64k (often far less) was a "big" system
Fast execution - Compilers keep getting better, but there is almost always room for improvement. As with code size, less of an issue today when clock speeds are measured in Gigahertz instead of Megahertz or even Kilohertz.
Low-level access to hardware - With some high-level languages, such as C, low-level access to the hardware is possible. With many other languages it is either tedious (BASIC PEEK/POKE) or impossible due to deliberate safety limitations built in to the language/compiler and/or the operating system.

I have written some assembly (a little bit on mainframes during college, a little bit on Intel x86 since then) but not lately. But if I needed to, I would learn assembly language for whatever CPU is needed for a customer's project. And if I started out doing everything in assembly language then I would have had to learn several new languages by now - either assembly language for new CPUs or high-level languages.
And if you haven't read it already, you have to read Raffzahn's story.

Even when writing C, an understanding of the target architecture's instruction set may be useful if one wants to ensure that generated code will neither be severely sub-optimal (worse than what a relatively mindless translator might produce) nor erroneous.

There's maybe also a very important third point: Library and/or Runtime support. If it's just about using C vs. Assembler, then basic C yields not much of an advantage - once either environment is set up. That little support standard C provides is also available in Assembler. It gets harder once additional libraries and especially frameworks tailored for C usage are involved. Here a start in C may save quite some time - not because of the language, but because of the ready to use environment. Otherwise, if that application specific enviromnmet has to be created first, the race is open again.

BTW, I LOVE that first paragraph :))

@Raffzahn It worked the other way, too — I remember being frustrated by a C development system whose library didn't provide bindings for OS calls and functions I needed.

(Just a comment because I don't have time to write an answer, plus there are 8 already:). Don't underestimate how much simpler things were then:  a) those few HLLs usable in production then were very simple by today's standards; and b) "software engineering" didn't exist, no O-O design, no "design patterns", etc. etc..  Those two things plus the fact that assembly language programmers were very close to the machine - much more than today's programmers!! - meant they had a very usable stable model to build on when understanding the simple HLLs of the time.

@davidbak, there have always been design patterns. It's just that, before the Gang of Four, we didn't know it was important to give them names. Also, when was this then that you speak of when things were simpler? Some of the comments here speak of assembly language programming in the 1980s and the 1990s. The phrase "software engineering" dates back to the mid 1960s, and object-oriented design goes back at least as far as SmallTalk (1972), maybe further back than that.

@SolomonSlow, I must admit those same thoughts occurred to me, but I assume what he means is that there wasn't the same amount of pretentiousness about the activity of "software engineering", that OO languages were not widely used industrially, and that "design patterns" tended to be ad-hoc and necessary to solve real problems rather than introduced into the code gratuitously. Above all, assembly corresponded very closely to the reality of what the machine was being instructed to do, and to the fundamental concepts of how computers work as machines.

There is one more argument as to why people write assembler still, in fact why I had to write an assembler snippet this week - control. With how insanely complicated modern compilers are, and how extensive the changes under C's (and C++'s) as-if rule are, I just wanted a guarantee that the code will do exactly what I want it to, at a very low level. Plus, in this particular part of code, I was messing with the stack pointer. ARM in fact even provides C functions that do what I wanted, but that didn't give me the necessary guarantees.

If you look at the source code for FreeRTOS - there is quite some amount of assembly still.

@jaskij: I wish the C Standard would include a mechanism for inserting raw bytes or words into a machine-code file, so as to allow a toolset-agnostic means of accomplishing tasks that otherwise require toolset-specific assembly-language constructs.  Sometimes it can be faster and easier for someone with a CPU manual to figure out the exact sequence of instruction bits necessary to do something, than to figure out how to format assembly code to make the toolset generate that sequence.

@supercat C23 added the #embed preprocessor directive. Meant for resources, not code, but I'm pretty sure it could be abused for that as well. Alternatively, you can just write plain assembly in a separate file and call that, much, much, easier than using inline assembly. That assembly function I had to write? It has literally three instructions. Still easier to make it a separate file than to use GCC's inline assembly.

@jaskij: I'm pretty sure that #embed only puts information into a data section.  On some platforms that may not matter, but on ARM platforms function calls need to use addresses whose LSB is set even though the storage location represented is word aligned.  Linkers take care of that with code sections, but not with data sections.

@jaskij: Further, the ability to insert raw hex bytes may in some cases be useful mid-function if implicitly treated as encompassing a "memory clobber" and optional register clobber (some instruction sequences would clobber few enough registers that having the compiler save/restore all used registers would be wasteful; some clobber enough registers that having a compiler save/restore all registers whose values it cares about would often be cheaper than having inline code save/restore all of them).  My point was that such things should be toolset agnostic--which assembly language isn't.

@supercat true, in the general case, assembler is not toolset agnostic, I can't argue with that. For the ARM case though, the major compilers (essentially just GCC and LLVM, as ARM's custom compiler is a fork of LLVM with a custom backend) actually use the same syntax. I wonder about the more niche stuff, like IAR.

@supercat I actually went and checked ARM's compiler, and they say there are minor differences between GCC and LLVM for assembly.

@jaskij: I don't trust ARM's present compiler.  Keil's own compiler (before it was abandoned in in favor of forking the Creative Language-Abusing Nonsense Generator) focused on low hanging fruit that yielded efficient machine code when fed source code whose structure matched that of efficient machine code.

I worked through the UK period where assembly programmers moved to C for embedded systems, throughout the 1980's. By and large, our clump of programming engineers quickly knew several assembly languages anyway (Z80, 6502, 6800, 68000, PIC) as we enjoyed learning new languages.
The move into C was gradual. May of us learnt the language though curiousity at scattered times, long before we got the chance to use it professionally. We continued to support the assembly programs while working in C so we worked on both for many years. I also looked into every programming language whose documentation came near me in those pre-internet days and learnt from their ideas (particularly learning C++ and Ada in depth much later).
We were trying to squeeze the maximum performance out of the limited CPU speeds back then, so efficiency was very important. Just churning out wish-list C, without a thought to the assembly instructions those more limited compilers/optimisers produced, would usually make a program too slow and/or too big. You really had to have a solid appreciation of how the CPU would do it to produce decent and worthwhile C programs.
These days, microcontrollers can nearly always have a lot of spare capability compared to the 1980s/1990s parts, for very little extra cost. It depends on your target market as to whether you can afford that extra cost but it's much more attainable now. So programs can be more inefficient and still get their tasks done in time, meaning it's not so essential for programmers to understand the CPU instructions generated by their C program. And compilers/optimisers have evolved in quality substantially.
Some of our team's examples are:

In 1990 and in development, two of us used 12 MHz 8752 MCUs (8052, 256 bytes RAM, 8 KB EPROM) at over £20 each (over £65 in 2024).

By 1994 and in production, cheapest for us was a 20 MHz 8032 MCU (8052, 256 bytes RAM) with external 32 KB EPROM totalling about £5 (£13 in 2024) for 10,000 parts/year.


Nowadays, it costs far less for an MCU going 32KB->64KB or 32KB-256KB Flash EPROM in same package. The latter would've been something like another £15 (£38 in 2024) for extra external EPROM in volume back in 1994. Such an MCU usually comes with at least 4..8 KB RAM, again far more than our 256 bytes, and has a far faster CPU.

C  was devised by and for programmers who already knew assembly language. Students who came from a FORTRAN background often found pointers and bit manipulation difficult to grok.

@JohnDoty: Unfortunately, the direction of the language is controlled by people who are clueless about what the things that makes the abstraction model used by assembly language useful in the first place.

Great points so far, but one hasn't come up so far:
Most just continued doing Assembly.
After all, the market they served didn't vanish. Not over night nor in long term. This was quite the case in mainframe environments, as those were quite stable up until today. It's the same way as why COBOL still thrives on mainframes. In this setting new Assembly developments, even larger ones, were started as late as 1990. Usually as part of an existing landscape, where continuing in Assembly was simply more effective than going thru the troubles of integrating other languages.

In addition the question may be based on a dual but intervened misconception of

programmer jobs being a limited offer as well as
High Level Languages being developed to improve existing development

Neither really holds true.
Assembly was all around excepted and regarded well fit. The real case for HLL came due the need for more programmers then there were and could be trained. Both major early Third Generation Languages(*1), FORTRAN and even more COBOL, were developed to allow every user to formalize their programming needs without having to train them as programmers(*2,*3). Fortran by simply writing 'standard' formula and COBOL by using plain English to describe business algorithm. That way every scientist, engineer, clerk and manager would be able to use a computer without needing a programmer turning his requirements into code.
We all know how this worked out: A huge demand for COBOL programmers next
Of course in some way they helped as they allowed user to change trade and becom programmers - after investing many hours (*4). Various powerful similar 3GL languages like (Business) BASIC tried the same for mini and later micro computer, again just creating the need for even more specialized programmers.
The late 70s/early 80s gave us a flood of 4GL, from Informix to ABAP, hyping empower Joe Average without needing to consult/employ programmers ... and failing again the same way.
Do I need to mention today's hype about AI enabling everyone to write needed software on the fly - or at least put real programmers out of ob by learning 'prompt generation'?
The wish to make machines program themself is strong enough to repeat history over and over. Same result every iteration. Plus new languages that were supposed to be the solution.

*1 - Machine code being 1st and Assembler being 2nd.
*2 - The third one, ALGOL and thus all of it's offspring, being an outlier in that theme as ALGOL did not focus on ease of handling but clear and stringent support of basic programming structures.
*3 - Of course there were as well special cases, from APL all the way to FORTH, but they are rather that, developments for very special application cases more DSL than general purpose.
*4 - Many might remember those guys from some department writing some super useful BASIC/Excel/whatsoever tool that had to be linked with the main system by order of management.

I daresay you can still find work in this language.

I know a some assembler programmers who learnt C because it started replacing some of their job or jobs - and often their assembler knowledge remained important, as (especially early) C wasn't really that close in to assembler in performance, and abstractions also leaked.

Not sure I like to think of machine code as a "language." But, if it must be one, and if it occupies level 1, then I propose; Level 0: microcode, and Level -1: hardware design.

@SolomonSlow That's simply the definition there is. Also, machine code as 1gl does not necessarily mean binary or hex, but whatever encoding used that the machine could read/store/execute without a translator software. Next, micocode is not a user side language (and introduced only after 1GL). last but not least Hardware design is as well not user side - nor programming at all. Plugboard may make an exception to the rule - albeit a rather far one.

@Trunk  parts in IBM z is still (macro)assembler,  so yes someone with good (macro)assembler knowledge prepared to train youngers can still find work.

@Stefan Skoglund  Maybe. I believe it's still used in simple controller CPU coding. It was the first language I learned as a Y1 engineering student . . . brings back terrible memories. So none of that for me !

The question seems to assume that a (good) programmer is either an assembly-level programmer or a high-level language programmer, and that a job description requires one or the other.
This doesn't square with my actual experience.  I'm hired to build things. Generally, I get to decide the implementation language, and this decision is not based on my preference, but my analysis of what is appropriate.
It is true that it's been a long time since I (professionally) wrote anything more than a couple of selected routines in assembler, but that doesn't change the nature of the job. A professional programmer is expected to pick up new tools and use them. I laugh at job descriptions that will only hire people who already use particular tools.

The whole point of "high-level languages" was that they were supposed to be easier to master and more productive than assembly. So there's no reason to think an already-competent assembly programmer, if he needed to reskill, would struggle to make himself useful in the marketplace.
Also, the "software crisis" has been ongoing since the 1960s, and each passing year draws more people into "programming" or the various trades which are ultimately allied to it.
That is, the general trend has always been toward expansion of the overall workforce, so there's never really been a mass of experienced software people who ended up on the scrapheap despite wanting to work.
Finally, the transition to high-level languages itself was not sudden but took decades, so the whole assembly workforce was never posed at once with a sudden need to retrain. Rather, entry-level jobs in pure assembly shrivelled, and it became harder for the oldest workers with assembly-only experience to battle on after an employer-specific redundancy and stay in the market without opting to retire, much as has become the case with COBOL.
Arguably what caused this gradualism is that even when high-level languages became available, the largest and most experienced workforce available were still those who knew assembly and whose training cost was already sunk.
So if you were starting a big new development and wanted a chance of it getting done, the choice is not freely between languages, it is between (a) the most widely available workforce (including software managers) with solid experience of assembly-based development, and (b) a narrower workforce consisting of older hands choosing to dabble with newer languages and compilers less familiar to them, together with the younger and less experienced. It takes quite a number of years after a specific language becomes available, before this labour market balance changes.
Other reasons for a long transition time include that there was a significant amount of installed assembly code that still had to be maintained and interfaced with, and that there were enough special cases where assembly exceeded the performance, reliability, or all-round usability of high-level languages and compilers that assembly continued to be used preferentially for new development for many years.

Assembler and high level languages require different skills to master; a master assembler programmer can probably become a journeyman high level language programmer with ease, and vice versa, but it isn't as if one is strictly harder than the other.  High level languages are assembly generators, and you can generate geometrically more code than you can write: at the extreme, it is like the difference between a woodworker and someone operating a machine that makes chairs, or even a machine that makes machines that make chairs.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont, there's some kind of learning curve, but it's still essentially data structures and algorithms. The jump from assembly to C is less like carpentry versus machine design, much more like hand tools versus power tools. You wouldn't expect a skilled hand carpenter, to struggle with the idea of using power tools.

Sure, so you get to journeyman for nearly free.  My standards of mastery are high.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont, in that era, the vast majority of programs were not written off the cuff, but typically went through extensive top-down design on paper (diagrams, flow charts, structured English). The main mastery in assembly was ekeing out every last bit of performance, and most of the basic structure of the program was already set by time any actual computer code came to be written. Moving the last step from assembly to say C, was a labour-saving and de-skilling event that still used most of the existing design methods, not really something that required even more mastery. (1/3)

The idea was that HLL compilers automated the decisions that assembly programmers performed at the last step of design, like choosing instructions and registers for a particular machine architecture and various kinds of optimisation. In practice though, by time compilers could do the analysis necessary for good optimisation, increases in computing power had rendered the optimisations increasingly non-crucial. So the replacement of assembly with HLL was driven by increased ease of use (i.e. lower skill), rather than out-competing what an contemporary assembly programmer could achieve. (2/3)

By time later HLL compilers actually were better than assembly programmers at optimisation, assembly had already fallen into disuse because in the meantime it had become technologically feasible to put up with slower, bulkier programs written in HLLs (and compiled with earlier, poorly-optimising compilers)! Whereas the inefficiency of HLL compilers had previously been intolerable during the heyday of assembly use, regardless of the human labour savings. (3/3)

@Steve: HLL compilers may be better than programmers in situations where code needs to be written once to handle multiple use cases, or on some platforms when code needs to be readily adaptable to other use cases, but on many platforms, a competent assembly language programmer could produce optimal code for many tasks even if an HLL compiler couldn't.

I think one thing that is missing from the answers and discussion is the exponential growth that occurred throughout this time.
When assembly was the only option, being a programmer wasn't really a separate role.  Everyone who maintained, worked with, or used a computer had to program it -- there wasn't any choice.
While some systems programs were ported from assembly to C (and other languages), the introduction of FORTRAN, COBOL, C (and other languages) also served to vastly increase the number of people who could write programs and the kinds of programs that could reasonably be developed.
At the same time, more and more computers were being developed, sold, deployed, and used.
If you're in something before a phase of explosive growth, you don't lose your job because of that growth.  For you, adopting C or FORTRAN or continuing to develop in assembly is as natural as it comes -- and there is constantly increasing demand for your skills.

This seems to compress C and FORTRAN into the same sort of time period. They were at least 16 years apart (more by the time C escaped Unix).

@dave Fair point, but now that we're some 70 years after the creation of FORTRAN,  that does seem a bit the same era (at least to the kids these days).  Most of the languages from that time did not survive, I kept my comment to those that did.  FORTRAN and COBOL were notable because they targeted specific applications beyond simply making a computer work -- they are languages developed specifically to expand the use of computing.  C is notable because it took over as the de facto systems programming language that replaced assembly in all by the niche areas where we still use it today.

@RobMcDonald: Regrettably, the Standard never recognized that the goal of C should be to behave in a manner consistent with a high-level assembler in all ways and cases that matter, and that there should be a means by which programmers can indicate which aspects of execution do matter.

I once wrote a device driver on the VAX/VMS operating system.
This was after mainstream programming had transitioned to high level languages. However, systems programming hadn't. The VMS operating system was (probably still is) mostly written in a special purpose language invented by the DEC (the manufacturer. I cannot recall the name of this language but it was somewhat lower-level than C). Drivers, however, were written in assembly.
Assembler really isn't that hard to pick up. The hard part is coding in an environment where absolutely any error is fatally bad. If you are lucky it crashed the system as soon as you loaded and used it. If you were unlucky it caused corruption that crashed the system seconds/minutes/days later!
So I expect the answer is that good assembly programmers became systems internals programmers, and less good ones learned a high-level language.
A third possibility is that they kept moving on "downhill" to smaller systems that didn't have C compilers. Programming TV remote controllers or keyboards with soft buttons. Or even, these days, flashlights. A colleague once moved on from PDP11 minicomputers to those newfangled microprocessors. Keep on to today, you have things like a PIC10F200, with 256 words of EPROM program storage and all of 16 bytes of RAM. I expect this is just about enough to program a flashlight to do Bright / Dim / Flashing / Off, but not using C. (link to PIC series data sheet). These six- and eight-legged beasties cost mere pennies today.
I will probably find a reason to tinker with such things in my retirement.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLISS may be the language you're thinking of.

Early VMS was mostly written in VAX MACRO (basically VAX assembly) and as @LAK mentioned some in BLISS.

I wrote the memory manager for a mainframe in assembler.
Then I wrote VB applications, and they were soaring and magnificent and beautiful. I wrote 3D graphics for the nuclear industry that nobody ever did on the PC. I could NEVER have done it  in assembler.
Before that, I was just a coder of data structures. But at the nuc place, the guys were all engineers, not programmers. I did these quick one off jobs that took almost no time (months) and made us huge money.
With all those VB system functions, I could add dozens of little irrelevant presentation details that made the program just SO much slicker and professional. Freed from assembly language, I won awards and was the company hacker elite.
And once hack, never back.

When programming in C, it's often useful to have an understanding of the target platform's machine architecture, and be able to judge whether the compiler is processing one's code in a manner that is reasonably efficient and that will satisfy application requirements.  Code-generation bugs in commercial compilers are rare, but they can happen, and have symptoms that would be impossible to diagnose without examining the generated code.  For example, in the 1990s I worked with a compiler for the 68000 series that would sometimes mis-adjust the stack pointer by 65,536 in a manner that wouldn't affect the behavior of the erroneous function, but would disrupt its caller's stack frame.  Someone who didn't understand 68000 assembly language would have had no hope of finding that problem.
While maintainers of free compilers would insist that the Standard allows them to process code in "interesting" ways, I doubt anyone who couldn't read ARM-Cortex M0 assembly code would be able to figure out how a function like:
uint16_t test(uint16_t *p)
{
  uint16_t temp = *p;
  return temp - (temp >> 15);
}

could return 65535, even if some outside process changed the value of *p during its execution.

Yep. I've never written any 68k assembly, but I've read many a line of it, debugging, or trying to coax the C optimizer to make it efficient.

@JohnDoty: Can you imagine how a compiler given the latter function could produce code that would behave as described?  The ARM Cortex-M0 is a 32-bit processor which supports 16-bit stores (sign agnostic) as well as signed and unsigned 16-bit loads.

I'm a physicist, not a language lawyer ツ. Perhaps if temp is 65534 and you have promotion to int 'cause 15 is an int?

@JohnDoty: Nope.  For some reason, gcc decides that computing temp + (int16_t)(temp >> 15)`` would be be more efficient than doing an unsigned shift and subtracting.  Weird, but okay I guess.  But then it decides that using a signed load for that would be better than using an unsigned load and sign extension, so it rewrites the expression as p - (((int16_t*)p) >> 15)`, performing both an unsigned load and a signed load.  If one load yields 0xFFFF and the other one yields zero (in either order), the function will return 0xFFFF.

I definitely agree.  Anyone working with a language that compiles to machine code should be able to read assembly because sometimes you need to be able to read the actual code to understand what went wrong.  I've never found any need to look under the hood with .NET, but understanding how data in memory works is still needed.

My reaction to that code is that the 'even if some outside process changed the value of *p' part cannot be guaranteed in the absence of volatile.  Am I wrong?

@dave: Some langauges like Java recognize the concept of a benign data race, and define the behavior of code containing them: a read which is subject to a data race will at worst choose in Unspecified fashion from among values the object has held or will hold.  The C Standard would allow C compilers to behave likewise, and people who learn to program with such languages may expect such behavior.  Someone who doesn't look at the generated assembly for that Cortex-M0 function would likely never guess that the machine code would read *p twice.  Although the C Standard does not forbid...

...such treatment, for many purposes the performance benefits of allowing programs to have benign data races may exceed any benefit that could be achieved by allowing compilers to "split" reads and do other things that would turn all otherwise-benign data races malignant.  With regard to this example, if calling code knew that *p had just been written, letting a compiler set temp to the value written (which would be forbidden by using volatile), rather than reading *p, would improve performance withtout violating the guarantee that the return value be 65534 or less.

In any case, my point was that someone who doesn't know how to look at generated assembly code or disassembled machine code would have no idea why generated code should care about whether the value of *p might change, since the hardware would define the behavior of reading p once even if some simultaneous event would try to change it, and there's no imaginable reason why it should be read more than once.

@supercat - right, the C language permits *p to be read twice. Which is why that code fragment is wrong. On second read, maybe that's what you meant all along.

@supercat I'm not sure what your point is with the example. Are you just trying to say that compiler bugs (which this is) are hard to diagnose without knowledge of the architecture's assembly language. This is trivially true.

@dave: Implementations are free to behave meaningfully in a wider range of circumstances than mandated by the Standard, and the Standard classifies code which relies upon such treatment as "non-portable or erroneous", i.e. "non-portable but correct" on some implementations but "erroneous" on others.  The code would be correct on configurations which are, by design, agnostic with regard to the possible existence of benign data races.

@JeremyP: Expand "compiler bugs" to include "surprising compiler behaviors".  The authors of the Standard intended and expected that many constructs behave identically on general-purpose implementations for commonplace platforms (GPIFCP), but wanted to allow other kinds of implementations to process them differently.  According to the published Rationale, when the C89 was written, there was no doubt about how a GPIFCP should process uint1=ushort1*ushort2; when ushort1 exceeds INT_MAX/ushort2;.  The Rationale describes how such implementations would process such a construct...

...in such cases, with the implication that there was no need to have the Standard mandate such behavior nor recognize a category of implementations that would behave that way, because they expected the fraction of implementations behaving that way to asymptotically approach 100%.  Only a small fraction of C code has been vetted to ensure it is free of constructs like that where the Standard doesn't mandate correct behavior, but the Committee would have viewed as astonishing any deviation from it.

Assembler coding is no longer relevant for developing new applications on mainstream computer systems, but there are lots of niches where it is still used:

Really small embedded systems.
Internals of larger systems: the lowest level of bootstrapping, the lowest level of math libraries, the lowest level of operating systems, sometimes device drivers, sometimes bindings for calling operating system functions from higher level languages, and many more.
Maintaining legacy systems written when assembler was more mainstream: lots of IBM mainframe stuff, some other old mainframes, and the like.
Anything that has to run fast benefits from knowing assembly language: I optimised a critical compare routine to its limits by writing C, reading the generated assembler, benchmarking and revising.
If you're working with newly developed platforms, you'll hit compiler bugs, and being able to read and debug the assembly language makes your bug reports much more useful.

There are more uses: those are just the commoner ones. Being able to learn and use a new assembly language quickly lets you solve problems that are too hard for many developers.
